# imagepicker+navigationController causing problems in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

how do i do this..i have appliation delegate...in which i added uinavigation controller through code...

here is my code...

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
HomeScreenController  *homeScreenobj=[[HomeScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeScreenobj]; 
[homeScreenobj release];  
   [window addSubview:navController.view];

// Override point for customization after app launch    
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

on homescreen i have a tabbar with three buttons here is an image

[image]

i want to take photo from library from imagepickerController...but getting weired issues

it is added to the main window i don't know why

here is an image for this

[image]

why this isn't shown fullscreen.... and also if i put this line

imagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = YES;

it hangs don't know why..here is my code to takePhoto....

```
-(IBAction)TakePhotoClicked
{
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = YES;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = 
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
//self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO];
//[imagePickerController release];
}
```

if i don't put this line to commented
//self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;

it shows like this

[image]

where clicking on home button take back to home...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to present the UIImagePickerController as a modal view controller. So don't push your controller, but present it as modal:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

You can pop the image picker using `-[UINavigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:]` to go back to the last view controller on the stack.